# batch file: tree /f is only listing current directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tree

I wrote a batch file `tree.bat` with following code:

> ```
> set output_loc=Z:
> set loc=Z:
> chdir /d %loc% & tree /f > "%output_loc%\tree.txt"
> ```

Let say the drive Z: has following tree

> ```
> foo1
>     file1
>     file3
>     file3
> foo2
>     file1
>     file2
>     tree.bat
> foo1
>     file1
>     file2
>     file3
> ```

When I run tree.bat I get the following output in Z:\tree.txt

> ```
> Folder PATH listing for volume storage1
> Volume serial number is C508-09ED
> Z:.
>     file1
>     file2
>     tree.bat
> No subfolders exist
> ```

How do I get the whole tree?

Comment: You are setting your variables to a drive unit, but you don't have indicated a folder. Try to replace Z: with Z:\

Comment: You should probably rename your batch-file into something different than tree because it might cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not name a batch file like any internal or external command! Otherwise, the command interpreter gets confused, like in your case.

The `tree` command (file name `tree.com`) you are using is searched in the current directory first, and if not found, it is searched in the directories given by the environment variable `PATH`. The executable file extensions are taken from environment variable `PATHEXT`. This all means that the batch file unintentionally `tree.bat` tries to rerun itself.

---

In addition, follow [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41974403#comment71126967_41974403) and replace `Z:` by `Z:\` to specify the root directory of drive `Z:`, as `Z:` specifies the current directory of the drive, which seems to be `Z:\foo2` according to your example (which is the directory containing the batch file).

Comment: renaming the .bat file to test.bat results same but changing the `loc` variable from Z: to Z:\ gives the expected result. Thanks to @MC ND